# Second-order Markov text generation?

Tags: information-theory, markov-chains, computational-linguistics

Looking at [this](https://youtu.be/WyAtOqfCiBw?t=1m45s) video starting at 1:45, the author claims to be using a second-order approximation for a Markov text generation. He has one letter which he outputs followed by another letter which tells him which state to go to - so in other words, he might first pick AC, so he outputs A and then goes to state C, where he picks CB, so he outputs C and goes to state B, etc. So he has a uni-gram output followed by a uni-gram transition piece of information.

But from my understanding, a second-order approximation would be like [this](http://www.decontextualize.com/teaching/dwwp/topics-n-grams-and-markov-chains/), with a bigram followed by a unigram as the "transition" state.

> This is the same character-level order-2 n-gram analysis of the (very
>   brief) text “condescendences” as above, but this time keeping track of
>   all characters that follow each n-gram:
>
> co    n
>
> on    d
>
> nd    e, e
>
> de    s, n
>
> es    c, (end of text)
>
> sc    e
>
> ce    n, s
>
> en    d, c
>
> nc    e
>
> The table above doesn’t just give us some interesting statistical
>   data. It also allows us to reconstruct the underlying text—or, at
>   least, generate a text that is statistically similar to the original
>   text. Here’s how we’ll do it: (1) start with the initial n-gram
>   (co)—those are the first two characters of our output. (2) Now, look
>   at the last n characters of output, where n is the order of the
>   n-grams in our table, and find those characters in the “n-grams”
>   column. (3) Choose randomly among the possibilities in the
>   corresponding “next” column, and append that letter to the output.
>   (Sometimes, as with co, there’s only one possibility). (4) If you
>   chose “end of text,” then the algorithm is over. Otherwise, repeat the
>   process starting with (2).

I'm extremely confused because both these sources consider themselves to be of order 2 in approximation, but it seems to me that the second source is of a higher order than the first. Is this true, or am I just completely misunderstanding what's happening?

Comment: N-Gram and Markov Order-N are different.  N-Gram is the number of letters in the pattern (gram) with no statistical information about what might follow it.  There is no 0-gram set of patterns.(well an empty set) .  Where an  Order-N Markov chain is the Number of dependent context that leads to symbol choices that follow it.  IE: Order-0 Markov has no previous context, thus is just the Statics of the symbols to choose from.  Order-1 Markov chain has 1 symbol of previous context and what choices follows it.  Order-2 Markov chain has a 2-Gram and what symbol follows it ...

Comment: @PhillipWilliams thank you - but I'm curious why the first example (the video) he considers it second order. Shouldn't that be first order?

Comment: What some people call order 1, other people call order 2.